# How to deal with this type of food eating friends?

Tags: friends, acquaintances, personal-hygiene, parties

Since my childhood I am still living alone because of this problem i.e food sharing problem with my own friends.

Suppose if I went to party, friends are also invited. They putting their hands in my plate and eat it, which I really don't like.  I am ready to share food, but putting their hands directly into my plate is a major problem for me. Sometimes they put their food into my plate which I feel is seriously disgusting. Actually I don't eat already consumed/used food.

How to deal with this type of food eating friends?

Comment: Where do you live? I think this is something that is highly affected by culture.

Comment: some of the people eat via hands, are they one of them?

Comment: "How to deal with these type of friends" is a very broad question that we cannot answer within the limits of a single post. Can you narrow down your question a bit? I think that "How can I get friends to stop interacting with my plate/food" would be something we can address, for example.

Comment: Additionally, do all or most of your friends do this when dining together? That will affect whether you can ask "don't put your hand into my plate" or not. If they all do that, you will get raised eyebrows.